# How to read this csv file in pandas (or python csv)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

How do I read this file in pandas? I tried using doublequote=True but that did not help.

Notice the comma within double quoted value.

```
"name","pos","age"
"billy","2","30"
"max",""5,5"","40"
```

Comment: It's not really a solution, but you could turn the csv into a big string, store it into a variable and use Regex to match quotes like this " and turn them into "". Then doublequote=true should work I guess

Comment: I was wondering if there was a set of configuration I could pass to pandas rather than roll my own.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to *fix* the file by reading it as a regular text file and cleaning up those double quotes. Then, read it as a regular `.csv` file and dump it to `pandas`.

See this:

```
import csv

import pandas as pd

with open("weird_file.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader([l.strip().replace('""', '"') for l in f.readlines()])
    print(pd.DataFrame(reader))
```

Output:

```
       0    1    2
0   name  pos  age
1  billy    2   30
2    max  5,5   40
```

Comment: What if I have "billy","2","30",""   would not your suggestion fail?

Comment: Only for that one row? If yes, then you have malformed data and you might be better off making sure you get the data in the right format in the first place. But to answer your question, the could will work but the dataframe will be different.